# Почему POST запрос выдает 400 ошибку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

Уважаемые коллеги, имеется следующий код:

```
      const checkboxes = {
    interactionId: this.interactionId,
    attributes: {
        accessServices: this.access.checked,
        processingPersonalData: this.personalData.checked,
        advertising: this.advertisingElement.checked,
        advertisingBank: this.advertisingBankElement.checked,
        smsMessage: this.smsElement.checked,
        photoVideoAudio: this.photoElement.checked,
        creditHistory: this.creditHistoryElement.checked,
        accessionService: this.accessionServiceElement.checked,
        accessionContract: this.accessionContractElement.checked,
        transmissionOthers: this.transmissionOthersElement.checked
    }
};

console.dir(checkboxes);


$.ajax({
   url: '/lalala/rest/offer',
   type: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify({   
    interactionId: this.interactionId,
        attributes: {
            accessServices: this.access.checked,
            processingPersonalData: this.personalData.checked,
            advertising: this.advertisingElement.checked,
            advertisingBank: this.advertisingBankElement.checked,
            smsMessage: this.smsElement.checked,
            photoVideoAudio: this.photoElement.checked,
            creditHistory: this.creditHistoryElement.checked,
            accessionService: this.accessionServiceElement.checked,
            accessionContract: this.accessionContractElement.checked,
            transmissionOthers: this.transmissionOthersElement.checked
        },
}),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json'
})
   .done(resp => {
       if (resp.status === 'COMPLETED' &&
        (resp.reason === 'ERROR' || resp.reason === 'CANCEL_CANNOT_EXEC' || resp.resultInfo)
       ) {
        this.addErrorTemplate(resp);
       } else {
        this.notify('sfoRouteTask', {taskId: resp.id, layout: resp.type});
       }
   })
   .fail(() => this.notify('sfoError', 'Ошибка загрузки данных'));
```

Почему этот запрос выдает ошибку 400?

Answer (score 0):

Cервер не может принять ваш запрос, так как ошибка возникает на сервере, то вам надо смотреть сервер лог. Если на сервере есть обработчик ошибок то возможно сообщение об ошибке будет перенаправлено в браузер. Поэтому иногда полезно знать в чем была ошибка при получении кода 400. Вы можете посмотреть сообщение об ошибке если будете его получать.

```
jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
```

Более подробно вы можете прочитать здесь как выполнять [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) запросы.